# Is it true that: $f(x,y)=constant \implies \nabla f(x,y)= \pmb{0}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2 \rightarrow R}$, be a differential function. Is it true that:
$$f(x,y)=constant \implies \nabla f(x,y)= \pmb{0}$$

I think this should be true since differentiability $\implies\exists\nabla$ and the partial derivative of a constant function is $0$. The answer to the problem is that it is false though, according to my book.

Comment: What does "$\forall (x,y), f(x,y)=$constant" mean ? If you write "$\forall (x,y)$" before "$f(x,y)=$constant", then the constant is allowed to depend on $x$ and $y$, and is no longer a constant...

Comment: Thanks for the observation, I have now edited.

Comment: It's the converse that is false.

Comment: @TedShifrin why is the converse false? I'm assuming OP meant $\nabla f =0$ identically on $\Bbb{R}^2$ rather than just a single point $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2$, in which case since $\Bbb{R}^2$ is connected we can deduce $f$ is constant using a mean-value inequality (or in this case the fundamental theorem of calculus also works).

Comment: True. If the domain is disconnected, it is false, whereas this direction holds regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clear that if

$$(\forall (x,y)\in \Bbb R^2)$$
$$\;f(x,y)=\;Constant\;=K$$

where $ K\in\Bbb R $, doesn't depend neither on $ x $, nor on $ y $,

we will have
$$(\forall (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=0\;\;
and \;\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=0$$